# What are causes of the vshost.exe fatal error?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, fatal-error

I am getting the following error with my program:

```
FatalExecutionEngineError occurred
Message: Managed Debugging Assistant 'FatalExecutionEngineError' has detected a problem in 'C:\Users\phill\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SkyLife Projects\SkylifeRadioApplication\SkylifeRadioApplication\bin\Debug\SkylifeRadioApplication.vshost.exe'.
Additional information: The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x7168e573, on thread 0x24ac. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.
```

I am not sure what could be causing this error in my C# application. I would like to post code but this error seems to be pretty random and sometimes happens when I simply move the application window around. I would really like to post some code on here but the issue is, it happens to error out at random times. Haven't quite pin pointed a sure fire way to generate the code. I apologize.

I am wondering, what are some common issues with the code that could be causing this error to happen? What are some common solutions that I can implement. (Also debugging techniques would be very helpful also as i am not to sure where to begin to debug an issue like this!)

Edit:

So it turns out that I do have some source that I can post. I am using a DLL and a c# source provided by a 3rd party. The source is using DLLImport (It is not a compatible dll file where I can simply import it via reference). Below are the methods to access the dll in the C# source:

```
[DllImport("SLABHIDDevice.dll")]
public static extern uint HidDevice_GetNumHidDevices(ushort vid, ushort pid);

[DllImport("SLABHIDDevice.dll")]
public static extern byte HidDevice_GetHidString(uint deviceIndex, ushort vid, ushort pid, byte hidStringType, StringBuilder deviceString, uint deviceStringLength);

[DllImport("SLABHIDDevice.dll")]
public static extern byte HidDevice_GetHidIndexedString(uint deviceIndex, ushort vid, ushort pid, uint stringIndex, StringBuilder deviceString, uint deviceStringLength);

[DllImport("SLABHIDDevice.dll")]
public static extern byte HidDevice_GetHidAttributes(uint deviceIndex, ushort vid, ushort pid, ref ushort deviceVid, ref ushort devicePid, ref ushort deviceReleaseNumber);

[DllImport("SLABHIDDevice.dll")]
public static extern void HidDevice_GetHidGuid(ref Guid hidGuid);

[DllImport("SLABHIDDevice.dll")]
public static extern byte HidDevice_GetHidLibraryVersion(ref byte major, ref byte minor, ref int release);

[DllImport("SLABHIDDevice.dll")]
public static extern byte HidDevice_Open(ref IntPtr device, uint deviceIndex, ushort vid, ushort pid, uint numInputBuffers);

[DllImport("SLABHIDDevice.dll")]
public static extern int HidDevice_IsOpened(IntPtr device);

[DllImport("SLABHIDDevice.dll")]
public static extern uint HidDevice_GetHandle(IntPtr device);

[DllImport("SLABHIDDevice.dll")]
public static extern byte HidDevice_GetString(IntPtr device, byte hidStringType, StringBuilder deviceString, uint deviceStringLength);

[DllImport("SLABHIDDevice.dll")]
public static extern byte HidDevice_GetIndexedString(IntPtr device, uint stringIndex, StringBuilder deviceString, uint deviceStringLength);

[DllImport("SLABHIDDevice.dll")]
public static extern byte HidDevice_GetAttributes(IntPtr device, ref ushort deviceVid, ref ushort devicePid, ref ushort deviceReleaseNumber);

[DllImport("SLABHIDDevice.dll")]
public static extern byte HidDevice_SetFeatureReport_Control(IntPtr device, byte[] buffer, uint bufferSize);

[DllImport("SLABHIDDevice.dll")]
public static extern byte HidDevice_GetFeatureReport_Control(IntPtr device, byte[] buffer, uint bufferSize);

[DllImport("SLABHIDDevice.dll")]
public static extern byte HidDevice_SetOutputReport_Interrupt(IntPtr device, byte[] buffer, uint bufferSize);

[DllImport("SLABHIDDevice.dll")]
public static extern byte HidDevice_GetInputReport_Interrupt(IntPtr device, byte[] buffer, uint bufferSize, uint numReports, ref uint bytesReturned);

[DllImport("SLABHIDDevice.dll")]
public static extern byte HidDevice_SetOutputReport_Control(IntPtr device, byte[] buffer, uint bufferSize);

[DllImport("SLABHIDDevice.dll")]
public static extern byte HidDevice_GetInputReport_Control(IntPtr device, byte[] buffer, uint bufferSize);

[DllImport("SLABHIDDevice.dll")]
public static extern ushort HidDevice_GetInputReportBufferLength(IntPtr device);

[DllImport("SLABHIDDevice.dll")]
public static extern ushort HidDevice_GetOutputReportBufferLength(IntPtr device);

[DllImport("SLABHIDDevice.dll")]
public static extern ushort HidDevice_GetFeatureReportBufferLength(IntPtr device);

[DllImport("SLABHIDDevice.dll")]
public static extern uint HidDevice_GetMaxReportRequest(IntPtr device);

[DllImport("SLABHIDDevice.dll")]
public static extern int HidDevice_FlushBuffers(IntPtr device);

[DllImport("SLABHIDDevice.dll")]
public static extern int HidDevice_CancelIo(IntPtr device);

[DllImport("SLABHIDDevice.dll")]
public static extern void HidDevice_GetTimeouts(IntPtr device, ref uint getReportTimeout, ref uint setReportTimeout);

[DllImport("SLABHIDDevice.dll")]
public static extern void HidDevice_SetTimeouts(IntPtr device, uint getReportTimeout, uint setReportTimeout);

[DllImport("SLABHIDDevice.dll")]
public static extern byte HidDevice_Close(IntPtr device);

[DllImport("SLABHIDtoUART.dll")]
public static extern byte HidUart_GetNumDevices(IntPtr device);


/* For the UART portion */
[DllImport("SLABHIDtoUART.dll")]
public static extern byte HidUart_GetNumDevices(ref uint num, uint vid, uint pid);

[DllImport("SLABHIDtoUART.dll")]
public static extern byte HidUart_GetString(UInt16 deviceNum, uint vid, uint pid, char[] name, UInt16 options);

[DllImport("SLABHIDtoUART.dll")]
public static extern byte HidUart_GetOpenedString(IntPtr device, char[] name, UInt16 options);

[DllImport("SLABHIDtoUART.dll")]
public static extern byte HidUart_Open(IntPtr device, UInt32 vid, UInt32 pid, UInt16 deviceReleaseNumber);

[DllImport("SLABHIDtoUART.dll")]
public static extern byte HidUart_Close(IntPtr device);

[DllImport("SLABHIDtoUART.dll")]
public static extern byte HidUart_SetUartEnable(IntPtr device, bool enable);

[DllImport("SLABHIDtoUART.dll")]
public static extern byte HidUart_GetUartEnable(IntPtr device, ref bool enable);

[DllImport("SLABHIDtoUART.dll")]
public static extern byte HidUart_Write(IntPtr device, char[] buffer, UInt32 numBytesToWrite, ref UInt32 numBytesWritten);

[DllImport("SLABHIDtoUART.dll")]
public static extern byte HidUart_Read(IntPtr device, ref uint buffer, UInt16 numBytesToWrite, ref UInt16 numBytesWritten);

[DllImport("SLABHIDtoUART.dll")]
public static extern byte HidUart_FlushBuffers(IntPtr device, bool flushTransmit, bool flushRecieve);

[DllImport("SLABHIDtoUART.dll")]
public static extern byte HidUart_GetUartStatus(IntPtr device, ref uint transmitFifoSize, ref uint recieveFifoSize, ref byte errorStatus, ref byte lineBreakStatus);

[DllImport("SLABHIDtoUART.dll")]
public static extern byte HidUart_SetUartConfig(IntPtr device, UInt32 baudRate, byte dataBits, byte parity, byte stopBits, byte flowControl);

[DllImport("SLABHIDtoUART.dll")]
public static extern byte HidUart_GetUartConfig(IntPtr device, ref UInt16 baudRate, ref byte dataBits, ref byte parity, ref byte stopBits, ref byte flowControl);

[DllImport("SLABHIDtoUART.dll")]
public static extern byte HidUart_SetTimeouts(IntPtr device, UInt16 readTimeOut, UInt16 writeTimeOut);

[DllImport("SLABHIDtoUART.dll")]
public static extern byte HidUart_GetTimeouts(IntPtr device, ref UInt16 readTimeOut, ref UInt16 writeTimeOut);
```

Comment: Well, the error message already points out some common causes for that problem: *"Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack"*... Are you using any COM-interop? Are you calling any methods of native DLLs (i.e. using `DllImportAttribute`)?

Comment: yes, I am using this DLL file and C# source provided by a 3rd party. The source is using DLLImport

Comment: You should probably verify those `DllImports` are actually using the correct pInvoke signatures, and all structures they send as parameters have the correct size and memory layout.  Most likely one of them is pushing something that isn't the size or shape that the method expects, and the stack or heap is getting corrupted when the method returns.

Comment: @BradleyUffner I see, thank you for the tip. I will check it out soon. Although, if the stack/heap becomes corrupted from one of the function calls, wouldn't the program error out right at the spot? It appears that there could be some delay between the error and when the program uses one of the calls. The program errors out during a timer when the program is not using one of the function call.

Comment: Well, there is no way for the runtime or operating system to detect the corrupted stack.  It is just a series of values that only have meaning the code that uses them.  If an extra value gets pushed to the stack that that doesn't get popped off at some point, then when the CPU tries to exit a function it will hit memory that isn't actually a proper return address.  That's when the error gets thrown.  It can happen far removed from the actual cause unfortunately.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Ah, ok, I see. I did not know that! Thank you for the information